# Как вывести несколько списков или сумму чисел через join без обьединения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Может кто-то посдсказать как вывести 3 списка через один join. Два списка содержат числа float. Пробовал сделать так. Но все время бросает разные ошибки.В первых двух вариантах sumaDebts и sumaOverdueDebts это не списки, а просто сумма чисел :

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, str('\n'.join(ordersname+map(str,sumaDebts)+map(str,sumaOverdueDebts))))
```

или вот так

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,str('\n'.join(ordersname))+"".join(str(x) for x in sumaDebts)+"".join(str(i)for i in sumaOverdueDebts)
```

И последний вариант, AllOverdueDebts и AllSumaDebts(это списки):

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, str('\n'.join(ordersname))+' '.join(AllSumaDebts)+' '.join(AllOverdueDebts))
```

Пример ошибки `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, в `join` попадает не строка, а число. А что такое `ordersname`?

Comment: @ Eurobeat Intensifies тоже список

Comment: @ Eurobeat Intensifies Да строк. Он жалуеться на AllSumaDebts, AllOverdueDebts, sumaDebts и на sumaOverdueDebts. Так как там где All это словари но с чисел но в них я записуваю suma.

Comment: Ну просто если есть три списка чисел, их можно вывести как `l1 = [1, 2, 3];  l2 = [4, 5, 6]; l3 = [7, 8, 9]; print('\n'.join(map(str, l1 + l2 + l3)))`; если в них будут строки, тоже должно работать

Comment: На самом деле, не очень просто понять вопрос: к примеру, приведённая ошибка -- она же относится к третьему варинту? В первых двух должна быть другая ошибка, наверное `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Eurobeat Intensifies я сделал так как вы показали и мне выдала ошибку 'float' object is not iterable. Здесь не три списка чисел, а всего два. + есть такая проблема что мне нужно вивысти числа из переменых suma или All для всех строк из ordersname. Пример: sample string1 0.0 0.0 '\n' sample string2 0.0 0.0 и так далее

Comment: Вы хотите взять слово из ordersname, одно число из AllSumaDebts, одно число из AllOverdueDebts, вывести их, вывести перенос строки и т.д. со следующими элементами?

Comment: @Eurobeat Intensifies Да.

Comment: Ну тогда должно быть что-то такое `'\n'.join(' '.join([w, str(n1), str(n2)]) for w, n1, n2 in zip(ordersname, AllSumaDebts, AllOverdueDebts))`, конструкция, может, неоптимальная, но вроде даёт нужный результат

Comment: @Eurobeat Intensifies спасибо большое

Comment: @Eurobeat Intensifies Прости ты немог бы подсказать как сделать это для списка в котором много значений, в примере который ты привел выше. Просто у меня выводит только первое значения из многих

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если списки выглядят подобным образом

```
ordersname = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']  # строки
AllSumaDebts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  # числа
AllOverdueDebts = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]  # числа
```

то с помощью конструкции

```
message = '\n'.join(' '.join([w, str(n1), str(n2)])
    for w, n1, n2 in zip(ordersname, AllSumaDebts, AllOverdueDebts))
```

У меня получается следующий результат (`print(message)`):

```
one 1 0.1
two 2 0.2
three 3 0.3
four 4 0.4
five 5 0.5
six 6 0.6
seven 7 0.7
eight 8 0.8
```

Здесь `zip(ordersname, AllSumaDebts, AllOverdueDebts)` делает список кортежей вида
`(ordersname[i], AllSumaDebts[i], AllOverdueDebts[i])` из исходных списков, и при помощи `for w, n1, n2 in ...` `w` принимает значение `ordersname[i]`, `n1` -- `AllSumaDebts[i]`, и `n2` -- `AllOverdueDebts[i]`. Можно вывести их строковые представления через пробел: `' '.join([w, str(n1), str(n2)]`

---

Не знаю, почему выводится одно значение, я бы проверил списки эти `(ordersname, AllSumaDebts, AllOverdueDebts)` непосредственно перед выводом. К примеру, Вы писали про числа (`sumaDebts` `sumaOverdueDebts`), может, какая путаница возникает и в списках оказывается не то, что ожидается.

---

**P.S.** рекомендую (если данный ответ не подходит, да и на будущее) максимально упрощать вопрос и приводить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), это действительно существенно помогает как отвечающим, так и самим авторам вопросов.

---

В случае, если списки `AllSumaDebts` и `AllOverdueDebts` гарантированно состоят из одного элемента:

```
ordersname = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']
AllSumaDebts = [0.0]
AllOverdueDebts = [0.0]
```

можно получить желаемую строку итерируя только по списку `ordersname`:

```
message = '\n'.join([' '.join(
    [w, str(AllSumaDebts[0]), str(AllOverdueDebts[0])]) for w in ordersname])
```

Вывод команды `print(message)`:

```
one 0.0 0.0
two 0.0 0.0
three 0.0 0.0
four 0.0 0.0
five 0.0 0.0
six 0.0 0.0
seven 0.0 0.0
eight 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: С списком ordersname впринципы все нормально. Это больше всего и за AllSumaDebts и AllOverdueDebts, так как у этих двух списков значения [0.0], поэтому оно наверное и выводит первое значения. Я сегодня пробовал это пофиксить, но безуспешно

Comment: @Key Они из одного элемента состоят или у них все значения одинаковы? Можете привести пример?

Comment: ordersname=[string № 30972201', 'string № 3682376010101', 'string № 2456222787', 'string № 3682376010101,...]

AllOverduDebts=[0.0]
AllSumaDebts=[0.0]

Comment: @Key тут дело в том, что `zip` возвращает кортежи, пока не закончится самый короткий список, а поскольку он из одного элемента состоит, то и заканчивается вывод после вывода одной строки. Получается, нужно, чтоб слова из `ordersname` выводились разные, а значения во второй и третьей колонках были всегда одинаковые? Можете привести пример желаемого вывода?

Comment: sample string1 0.0 0.0 '\n' sample string2 0.0 0.0 '\n' ...

Comment: @Key я обновил ответ (но только для случая, когда точно известно, что нужно брать первые (с индексом 0) элементы из списков `AllSumaDebts` и `AllOverdueDebts`)

Comment: спасибо большое помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
def _to_str(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, (tuple, list, set)):
        return ', '.join(map(_to_str, obj))
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return ', '.join(f'{k}: {_to_str(obj[k])}' for k in obj)
    return str(obj)

def to_str(*objs):
    return ' | '.join(map(_to_str, objs))

a = 1
b = {1: {'asd': 2, 'asd123': [{1, 4}, 5]}, 'a': [None], }
c = ['arty', 'z3', 3]
print(to_str(a, b, c))  # "1 | 1: asd: 2, asd123: 1, 4, 5, a: None | arty, z3, 3"
```